# Меню в мобильной версии не закрывается автоматически при клике на пункте из меню?

Tags: javascript, html

```
// Burger Menu
var burgerMenu = function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.js-fh5co-nav-toggle', function(event){
      

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( $('#ftco-nav').is(':visible') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active'); 
        }
    });
};
burgerMenu();


var onePageClick = function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#ftco-nav a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 70
    }, 500, function() {
        // window.location.hash = href;
        
        
    });
    });
};


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ftco_navbar bg-dark ftco-navbar-light site-navbar-target" id="ftco-navbar">
    <div class="container">
    
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="tel: +7 (964) 531-29-99">+7 (964)<span> 531-29-99</span></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ftco-nav" aria-controls="ftco-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="oi oi-menu"></span> Меню
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home-section" class="nav-link"><span>Главная</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about-section" class="nav-link"><span>О нас</span></a></li>
          
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><span>Контакты</span></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#karta" class="nav-link"><span>Мы на карте</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что при нажатии на пункт меню само меню не сворачивается и закрывает половину видимости и нужно тапнуть по меню второй раз, чтобы оно закрылось. Задача сделать автозакрытие меню при клике на пункт меню.

Answer (score 0):

Не особо понял проблему. Могу предоставить немного улучшенный код, исходя из того, что я увидел в вашем. Если какие-то значения неверны, можете поменять.

```
/* Nav Toggle */
let nav = $('#ftco-nav');
let navToggle = $(".js-fh5co-nav-toggle");

navToggle.on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    nav.toggleClass("active");
});

/* Close menu */
$(".btn").on("click", function(event) { nav.removeClass("show"); });
```

Вместо .btn поставьте ваш класс кнопок, data кнопок или что-то иное.

Comment: Проблема в том, что при нажатии на пункт меню само меню не сворачивается и закрывает половину видимости и нужно тапнуть по меню второй раз, чтобы оно закрылось. Задача сделать автозакрытие меню при клике на пункт меню.

Comment: @Алексей, попробуйте при клике в любой ситуации на пункт меню делать nav.removeClass("active")